# C++ duplicate stdout to file by redirecting cout

Tags: c++, boost, stdout, iostream

Good day.

I have to use some external functions that produce a lot of debugging information to stdout (via `std::cout`). I want to duplicate this information to some log file by redirecting `cout` to boost `tee_device`. I use the following example code:

```
typedef boost::iostreams::tee_device<ostream, ofstream> TeeDevice;
typedef boost::iostreams::stream<TeeDevice> TeeStream;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    remove("file.log");
    ofstream logFile;
    logFile.open("file.log");
    TeeDevice outputDevice(cout, logFile);
    TeeStream logger(outputDevice);    

    cout.rdbuf(logger.rdbuf());
    cout << "some log info";//this should print both to stdout and to file

    logger.close();
}
```

However I have a segmentation fault when trying to run this. Why?

I know that I can do like

```
    logger << "some debug log info";
```

but I need exactly to redirect `cout`. How I can obtain this?

Thanks, 
Stanislav

Comment: What horrible external functions writes logging to cout ? There's no standard way to capture that except to externally pipe the output to a file. Do you have the source code for it?

Comment: I have a source, but, unfortunately, I can not modify it. The functions I use are a part of a big scientific framework for particle physics (PandaRoot). Unfortunately, printing a debugging info just to `stdout` is a common problem for many scientific programs (

Comment: Have you checked that you're able to create the file? `assert(logFile.good());` or similar? Have you run it under a debugger to see where it crashes?

Comment: Yes, file is good. This is not a problem.

Comment: I've run it under debugger and it shows that crash occurs in method `boost::iostreams::flush(std::ostream)`.

Comment: I am not sure that calling `rdbuf(...)` on `cout` with a buffer derived from `TeeStream` is legal (however compiler does not produce even warnings). I just tried a naive solution and it fails, but I do not know a correct one.

Comment: @JohanLundberg ISO C++: `std::cout` has type `std::ostream`.

Comment: @EvgenyPanasyuk, yes - I misread the standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set `TeeDevice` output to `std::cout`, and then substitute it's `rdbuf` with one which depends on `TeeDevice` (which depends on `std::cout`).

Problem is solved by breaking that cycle via temporary `std::ostream` which holds pointer to original `rdbuf` of `std::cout`:

```
int main()
{
    remove("file.log");
    ofstream logFile;
    logFile.open("file.log");

    ostream tmp(cout.rdbuf()); // <----
    TeeDevice outputDevice(tmp, logFile); // <----
    TeeStream logger(outputDevice);    

    cout.rdbuf(logger.rdbuf());
    cout << "some log info" << endl;

    logger.close();
}
```

[**Live Demo on Coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c4729dd796c5daf)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `freopen` function. Here is an example and comment from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/freopen/):

> This function is especially useful for redirecting predefined streams
>   like stdin, stdout and stderr to specific files (see the example
>   below).

```
/* freopen example: redirecting stdout */
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  freopen ("myfile.txt","w",stdout);
  printf ("This sentence is redirected to a file.");
  fclose (stdout);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Duplicating* stdout is much harder than just redirecting it.

Comment: This just replaces `stdout` to `myfile.txt`. The OP wants to write to `stadout` AND `myfile.txt`