# Redirect output to file and ask user input

Tags: c++, linux

Is there a way to redirect the console output to a log file while also allowing the console to ask the user for their input with the text? From what little I know about Linux, to redirect console output to a file one would simply type the following `./Executable > output.log` or `./Executable | tee output.log`.  Now if, for example, I try that on the below code:

```
int main(){
    std::string name;
    std::cout << "ENTER NAME: ";
    std::cin >> name;

    std::cout << "Welcome! So your name is '" << name << "'" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The console would simply have a blinking cursor initially or output everything and store copy in file. What I am hoping is would it be possible to have the console output only "ENTER NAME: " but not "Welcome! So your name is 'Test'.

Thanks

Comment: I think you need http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/freopen/

Comment: Yes, you can do that. See http://wordaligned.org/articles/cpp-streambufs.

Comment: Also, if you have the option of using `boost`, you can use `boost::iostreams::tee_device`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19641190/c-duplicate-stdout-to-file-by-redirecting-cout.

Comment: @J3soon thanks for introducing me to freopen! But what I was aiming at was having just select parts of the code print on console!

Comment: @RSahu sadly no I cannot make use of boost! limitations from higher up...

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible .There are two possible ways of doing it .
First and simpler one is to open a log file and write output to that .

```
int main(){
    std::string name;
   ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("log.txt");
    std::cout << "ENTER NAME: ";
    std::cin >> name;

    std::cout << "Welcome! So your name is '" << name << "'" << endl;
  myfile << "Welcome! So your name is '" << name << "'" ;//write to the file.
  myfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Second , if you wnt to redirect the output just like the linux . You can do that by running linux command by using "system" call .

Answer (score 0):

There is an even simpler way; just use `cerr` (which isn't redirected by `>` or `|`) instead of `cout` to output the prompt:

```
    cerr << "ENTER NAME: ";
```